# How to search for a specific phrase in a .txt file using batch

Tags: string, batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file that will search a .txt file for a specific word and give me a response based on the word found. But when i search for "time" and "timer", they both give the same response as if it only found "time". Is there any way i can search for the whole word or a whole series of words and not just a fraction of the word?

I've tried quoting the words and double quoting the words/phrases but it still gives the same response

This is a section of the code:

```
:: Searches for the word "time" and if found, runs the file "Time.bat" in the folder, modules

:Q3
find /I "Time" CurrentConversation.txt
if errorlevel 1 (
    goto :Q4
) else (
    Call Modules/Time.bat

)


:: Searches for the word "timer" and if found, runs the file "Timer.bat" in the folder, modules

:Q4
find /I "Timer" CurrentConversation.txt
if errorlevel 1 (
    goto :Q5
) else (
    call Modules/Timer.bat

)
```

I expected that if the file "CurrentConversation.txt" had the word timer then it would run "Timer.bat". And that if the file had the word time then it would run "Time.bat" but instead it only runs "Time.bat" regardless of the word timer being present

Comment: because `Time` exists in `Timer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some better ways to achieve this, but to stick to your current code..
You need to realise that the string `Timer` also contains `Time` so if it will launch `time.bat` as the search matches. So let's rather use `findstr` and we tell it to search for `Time` ending `\>` so that it does not match `Timer` when searching for `Time`.

```
:Q3
findstr /I "Time\>" CurrentConversation.
if not errorlevel 0 goto :Q4
Call Modules\Time.bat

:: Searches for the word "timer" and if found, runs the file "Timer.bat" in the folder, modules

:Q4
findstr /I "Timer" CurrentConversation.txt
if not errorlevel 0 goto :Q5
call Modules\Timer.bat
```

I also made some changes to get rid of the code blocks, it is not needed here.. We just test for `if not errorlevel 0`. Once it does not meet that `errorlevel` it will fall through to the `call bat.bat`. If however it is anything other than `errorlevel 0`it will run goto.

Also, another way to do the line mathcing would be a double findstr to include and exclude, but it is a bit of an overkill.

```
findstr /I "Time" CurrentConversation.txt | findstr /VI "Timed" test.txt CurrentConversation.txt
```

See help from cmd.

- `findstr /?`
- `if /?`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that as a single line in a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)

```bat
For %%A In (Time,Timer)Do FindStr /IRC:"\<%%A\>" "CurrentConversation.txt">Nul&&Call "Modules\%%A.bat"
```

Just propagate the content between the parentheses with your comma or space separated words, and you should be good to go.